# change boolean in Access to false using ASP Classic

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, asp-classic, boolean

I'm trying to use some asp to change a booolean value within my database to true or false based on if theyre true or false already

```
prodRs.Open "Select * FROM product WHERE prod_ID LIKE " & request("prod_ID"),conx, adOpenkeyset,     AdLockOptimistic

If prodRs("prod_hidden ")="True" Then
sql_comd="UPDATE product SET prod_hidden = False where prod_ID LIKE '" & request(" prod_ID") &"'"
Else
sql_comd="UPDATE product SET prod_hidden = True where prod_ID LIKE '" & request(" prod_ID") &"'"
End if
```

when i print out prod_hidden it will tell me its false, but i can never change it to true. Doesn't give me an error, just runs the redirect i have at the bottom of the page

response.writing the sql and running it in Access works, just not within this asp

Comment: What happens if you add single quotes to your SQL, ie `UPDATE product SET prod_hidden = 'False' where...`

Comment: It gets the same result as without the single quotes around it. @John

Comment: It looks as if "true" and "false" aren't the actual values stored in the .mdb database, they're just what the Access front end application displays.  See this http://www.upsizing.co.uk/Art49_BooleanInView.aspx

Comment: I've tried -0, =-1,=true and =false but unfortunately none of those will change the boolean when the sql_comd is run @John

Comment: Could you add a bit more code. Where have you put `conx.Execute(sql_comd)`

Comment: It was directly below that If statement. I WOULD give more code, but as I worked on it, I kind of cheated and changed the prod_hidden field a string with a validation rule of only allowing true or false, which does make everything work, but is a convoluted and inefficient way of solving this @John

Comment: I have some concerns about the leading or trailing spaces in strings like '("prod_hidden ")' and '(" prod_ID")'. Also no idea what is being returned by 'request(" prod_ID")'. Have you tried copying the sql that is GENERATED and running it in Access as a SELECT query to see if you get any records?

Comment: Have you tried `If CBool(prodRs("prod_hidden ") & "") Then`? You don't need the `= True` as it is `True` by default. Both `Bit` and `YesNo` field types should produce VBScript style Boolean values `True = -1` and `False = 0`. What data type is your `prod_hidden` field?

Comment: One thing worth mentioning- get out of the habit of doing queries like, `LIKE " & request("prod_ID")` as soon as you can.  This makes your code and database extremely vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).